# finding the best match

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to find best match value from table T2 with respect to the value in table T3. For example, here I am expecting to get 441 as result.

Please advise.

Thanks.

```
create table t3 (rc varchar2(20));
create table t2 (rcs varchar2(20));

insert into T3 values ('441449729804');
insert into T2 values ('44');
insert into T2 values ('441');
commit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever have a single row selected from `t3` then:

```sql
SELECT t3.rc, t2.rcs
FROM   t2
       INNER JOIN t3
       ON t3.rc LIKE t2.rcs || '%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(t2.rcs) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

If you can have multiple rows from `t3` and want the best match for each then:

```sql
SELECT t3.rc,
       t2.rcs
FROM   t3
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT rcs
         FROM   t2
         WHERE  t3.rc LIKE t2.rcs || '%'
         ORDER BY LENGTH(t2.rcs) DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t2
```

or:

```sql
SELECT rc,
       rcs
FROM   (
  SELECT t3.rc,
         t2.rcs,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t3.rc ORDER BY LENGTH(t2.rcs) DESC) AS rn
  FROM   t2
         INNER JOIN t3
         ON t3.rc LIKE t2.rcs || '%'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for your sample data, all output:

| RC | RCS |
| --- | --- |
| 441449729804 | 441 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CWp6jnZR)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much. What I was trying was not giving me the maximum best match but  minimum match instead. Grateful for your help.